# I can see the plugins in the cpanel but i cant see it in wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cpanel

hello as the titles says I can see the plugins in the cpanel but i cant see it in wp dashboard. i tried everything 'i'm using the wp root admin when i go to the wordpress dashboard. Also the plugin folder is set to 755. I tried to install a wordpress plugin via searching and it says that I can't create a directory, I tried manually uploading a zip file still same results.

Answer (score 1):

Showing the Folder in CPanel doesn't mean that Plugins are OK. Please check the files which may have issues.

Answer (score 0):

My theory based on what you've described is that this is a Linux user permissions issue. So the Linux user used by WordPress doesn't have permissions to make changes.

Check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202544/which-is-the-user-used-by-wordpress

Comment: hello thank you for replying. I can upload files on the plugin folder using the cpanel but when i ake a look the my wordpress plugin section i cant see it

Comment: Without knowing much about the site then it's possible the the WordPress install may have been configured to not allow plugins to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

hello as the titles says I can see the plugins in the cpanel but i cant see it in wp dashboard. i tried everything 'i'm using the wp root admin when i go to the wordpress dashboard. Also the plugin folder is set to 755. I tried to install a wordpress plugin via searching and it says that I can't create a directory, I tried manually uploading a zip file still same results.

If you see the plugin on the file manager of the Cpanel; but you are not able to see it on the wp-admin dashboard. This can probably mean that it is not installed correctly. Try removing the plugin and install it from the plugin search section on your wordpress admin plugin menu.

Please send me screenshots and try to explain it with more details so I can understand better and be able to help..

Comment: heres the plugin list on my cpanel 
https://www.screencast.com/t/KjdxD3xf9jG

when i go to the wordpress dashboard on plugins section there is nothing there
https://www.screencast.com/t/iCiWcqYKiFui

i tried your suggestions still not working heres a screenshot of the error when i install the plugin in wordpress
https://www.screencast.com/t/mZ9FmJZ0s

Comment: This is definitely a permision problem. Set the complete wp-content folder to 777 just to see if this is the problem. After doing this, INMEDIATELY put permisions back to 775 and tell me what happen so I can help you with the right permisions.

Answer (score 0):

There was space in the name of the folder name, which cause the folder to appear in wordpress dashboard

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

- Go to your cpanal /public_html/wp_content/
- Select plugins and rename  it to "plugins"
- Actually after plugins there was extra space. Just remove that extra space.

You are done. Now you have to reactivate all plugins from your wordpress dashboard.